# Change wallpaper based on times desktop has been shown

Tags: desktop-background

I want to create a wallpaper slide show that will not change five minutes after the wallpaper gets displayed, but five minutes after the **entire** desktop get viewed. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned - if you feel this is in error, then please ask a new question, or flag this explaining why and the moderators will reopen it.

Answer (score -1):

What if you check with "Xlib python library" or "wmctrl and xwininfo commands" what windows are not minimized? (Filtering windows like gnome-panels, etc). Depending on values (all app windows are minimized = entire desktop get viewed) and selected time delay you can create a xml slideshow with desired background image.

Comment: If I were to create and XML slideshow, I would need to keep updating that XML file. Do the XML files get refreshed when changing to a new image? If so, how can I add to that XML file from the command line?

Comment: Instead of adding a new image background to the xml file, create full xml:

<background><starttime></starttime>

<static><duration>1</duration><file>$lastImageBackground</file></static>
<transition><duration>$transitionTime</duration>$lastImageBackground<from></from><to>$newImageBackground</to></transition>

<static><duration>1000</duration><file>$newImageBackground</file></static>

</background>